# Puppet Exec fails executing useradd

Tags: puppet

From what I understand, puppetd runs as root. As root, I launch

```
 puppetd --onetime --no-daemonize --verbose
```

So I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
exec { "useradd -m testuser":
       path => "/bin:/usr/bin",
     }
```

I just get:

```
...Exec[useradd -m testuser]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed:useradd -m testuser returned 1 instead of one of [0] at...
```

If I execute the command directly, it works just fine.

Any ideas?

PS: exec { "touch /root/a.test":} is successful, so it is indeed executing as root.

PS2: I get the exact same problem when executing "apt-get autoremove"

Comment: What OS is this on?

Comment: It's on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Have you moved useradd? Puppet execs will not inherit the default path values from a host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in most systems useradd will be in one of the sbin folders rather than /bin or /usr/bin. your path should be `"/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin",`. though this solution is rather horible i would use the user type rather than an exec it will give you much better management of users on a host (checks on pw and existance requires etc)

```
@user {
  "testuser":
    uid => ,
    gid =>,
    password => #hash of password,
    home => ,
    groups => ,
}
```

this is a virtual resource and can be added to your host by `realize ( User[testuser])` allowing it to be referenced multiple times

it's a nice simple solution

Comment: The path unfortunately isn't the problem. And regarding the user type, you are right... see above.

Comment: After a lot of investigation it appears that the path was indeed the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try running the command with:

```
exec { "useradd -m testuser":
  path => "/bin:/usr/bin",
  logoutput => true,
}
```

And see what it says. It should give you error on the command line now. Also 'on_failure' is another option which only outputs when the command fails. I usually do:

```
Exec {
  logoutput => on_failure,
}
```

As a default so all my commands output something meaningful globally if they fail.

But normally - you would use the 'user' resource instead:

```
user { "myusername":
  ensure => present,
  managehome => true,
}
```

Well documented here alone with other resource types:

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/user.html

Comment: I can't seem to find the output log. Although it's set as  /var/log/puppet/ in puppet.conf, that directory is empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you run puppet on the command line you should see it in the report 'puppet agent -t' ... test it works by just using 'echo foo' in another exec resource.

Comment: -t is not a valid option... By running _puppetd --onetime --no-daemonize --verbose --logdest /var/log/puppet/log --debug_ I get some more info but nothing useful about why useradd is failing.

Answer (score 1):

It *works* but does it return 1 instead of 0 ?  Try running `echo $?` after that `useradd` command.

You tend to get better error messages by using the built in Puppet types rather than exec like this:

```
user { "foo":
  ensure => present,
  uid => 1001,
  password => '<some password hash>',
  shell => "/bin/bash",
  home => "/home/foo",
  groups =>  ["foogroup"],
  managehome => true,
}
```

Is there any reason you're using exec instead of doing that ?

Comment: No it doesn't work.
The useradd part is actually part of a larger script that syncs users with a sql table. I'd love to do the sync through puppet but I wouldn't know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the Ruby Shadow gem in order to work with /etc/shadow

```
sudo apt-get install libshadow-ruby1.8
```

or in redhat/fedora

```
sudo yum install ruby-shadow
```

Comment: it is already installed, latest version.